# Eclipse PHP debugging as "Web application" with xdebug zend is not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

I configured PHP Xdebug with apache server and using Chrome. And it was working but then I played with other configuration and breakpoints stopped working.

So originally my working configuration is like this:

my php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.26/zend_ext/php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll"
;xdebug.mode allowed are : off develop coverage debug gcstats profile trace
xdebug.mode =debug
xdebug.output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.log="c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug2.log"
;xdebug.log_level : 0 Criticals, 1 Connection, 3 Warnings, 5 Communication, 7 Information, 10 Debug Breakpoint
xdebug.log_level=7
;VBE change: ;xdebug.profiler_output_name=trace.%H.%t.%p.cgrind
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.use_compression=false
xdebug.client_port = 9002
xdebug.client_host = localhost
```

Window->Preferences->PHP->Server->Default PHP webserver

Server tab:

[image]

Debugger tab:

[image]

Window->Preferences->PHP->Debug

[image]

Window->Preferences->PHP->Debug->Debuggers->XDebug

[image]

Then I click Run->Debug as->PHP Web Application

Then it offers "Launch URL" dialog. I had to change path from
`http://localhost/wp_leo/1/vbe_get_mem.php`
to
`http://localhost/3/1/vbe_get_mem.php`

as Eclipse uses name of the project which is `wp_leo` but my actual path on server is just `3`.

Then first time breakpoint worked. But then I played with configurations and at some point breakpoint stopped working. I got just "Break at first line" as it was checked in Window->Preferences->PHP->Debug. But all other breakpoints were ignored. So the question is why my breakpoints are ignored??????????

Answer (score 2):

Path mappings should be directories, not URIs (such as `http://`).

Comment: Yes I guess that was my mistake. But eclipse is kinda broken and 2 settings are kinda fighting. Even when I used directories I ended up with debugger not working and had to fixed it in other place. See my further fight and win: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984575/1093607

Answer (score 0):

So after some eclipse crazy clicking I went to xdebug.log file. Searching for `breakpoint` and I got lucky there is command `breakpoint_set`. So I found:

```
[22360] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 897 -t line -f file:///http://localhost/3/1/vbe_get_mem.php -n 18
[22360] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="897" id="223600006"></response>
```

The path `/http://localhost/3/1/vbe_get_mem.php -n 18` is actually correct path. But it does not work. I was wondering that maybe `file:///` and `http://` is weird combination. So I tried my debuger in CLI mode where breakpoint worked and there was used path:

```
[20048] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 967 -t line -f file:///C:%5Cwww%5C3%5C1%5Cvbe_get_mem.php -n 18
```

Which looks wild but was working. So `%5C` is used instead of `/`. My document root is `c:/www/` and path on server is `3/1/vbe_get_mem.php`.

Actually one thing that I was trying to configure was mapping path. Because I didn't like that every new file I debugged offered wrong path using project name instead of actual path on server and I need to manually rewrite it... So I played with Window->Preferences->PHP->Servers->Default PHP Web Server->Tab "Path Mapping". And probably that was mistake. Solution was to delete everything there and make it empty. Like this:

[image]

then breakpoint started working. And the path in xdebug.log started looking same as in CLI mode:

```
[16188] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 1972 -t line -f file:///C:%5Cwww%5C3%5C1%5Cvbe_get_mem.php -n 9
```

btw note that upon first running debug it asks for folder and it uses project name instead of actual server directory. So you need to rewrite that first time you start debugger. Or I find solution how to [fix debug path in project settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984575/1093607)

Good luck...