# Eclipse debug PHP Web Application offers wrong launch URL (using project name which differs from actual path on server)

Tags: eclipse, debugging

When I start to debug new PHP file using Run->Debug As->PHP Web Application, then Eclipse always offers wrong URL path like this:

[image]

`http://localhost/wp_leo/1/vbe_get_mem.php`
But actual path is:
`http://localhost/3/1/vbe_get_mem.php`
Basically Eclipse offers my project name `wp_leo` in the default URL, but my actual path on web server is just `3`.

How do I change default path so every time I debug new PHP I do not need to change it manually??

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project->Properties->Debug`
Check `Enable project specific settings`
Then in `Default Base URL->Base path` change `/wp_leo` into `/3`

[image]

Then **VERY IMPORTANT THING**. Sometimes the debugger is broken by this. And breakpoints stop being respected... Code just run... To fix this go to 
`Window->Preferences->PHP->Server->Default PHP Web Server->tab Path Mapping`
and delete everything what is there. So it is empty like this:
[image]